# Format Double in Currency format so that it has two zeros after the decimal point, rather than 1

Tags: java, double, currency, zero, decimal-point

I currently have a `Double` which is supposed to be displaying a Currency. However when the Double is actually displayed, it only shows data like this: "32.0". I would instead like it in the format of "32.00". Is there any way to fix the way a Double is formatted and how many figures show after the decimal point?

Comment: "I currently have a Double which is supposed to be displaying a Currency." - that's a bad start. Don't use binary floating point values for currency. Use BigDecimal, or an integer value with implicit scale (e.g. an integer number of cents.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use doubles to store money amounts. Use BigDecimal instead. You don't want rounding errors, inherent to floating point arithmetic, when dealing with money.

Second, use java.text.DecimalFormat to format your numbers.